# longtabu problem: what have I missed?

Tags: tabu

Can someone check the reproducibility of this non-compilation?

Here is the LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\include{defs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\underline{Directives}\\[5mm]
\begin{longtabu}to \linewidth{X|XXX}
{\em Type} & {\em Form}      & {\em Example} & Function \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
{\em Type} & {\em Form}      & {\em Example} & Function \\
\hline
\endhead
{\em Type} & {\em Form}      & {\em Example} & Function \\
\hline
\endfoot
{\em Type} & {\em Form}      & {\em Example} & Function \\
\hline
\endlastfoot
reaction   & millibarns      & {\tt millibarns}      & All total cross
             sections for the reaction are in millibarns.\\
           & sigma(n1,n2)    & {\tt sigma(.5,1)}     & \\
\hline
energy     & fractional error& {\tt fractional error}& The error for the
             total cross section is multiplied by the total cross 
         section. \\
           & per cent error  & {\tt per cent error}  & The error for the
         total cross section is multiplied by $0.01\sigma$. \\
           & shift           & {\tt shift smith77}   & The blank delimited
         characters comprise the energy shift identifier.\\
       & variable energy\newline free energy & {\tt variable energy 
         = engy7} & The blank delimited characters identify the energy 
         as free to vary. \\
       & reverse particles & {\tt reverse particles} & The order
         of the initial particles is reversed. \\
       & points & {\tt 5 points} & The data is energy-averaged
         over 5 points. \\
       & resolution & {\tt resolution = .05} & Resolution is
         half the width in MeV of the experimental energy resolution
         for the energy-averaged.{\bf [CHECK!]} \\
       & Gaussian & {\tt gaussian} & Data is energy-averaged
         assuming Gaussian energy distribution. \\
\hline
observable & label\newline header & {\tt label = Smith Ayy} & This is 
             the label printed with the observable. Only 56 characters are
         printed. No directive is allowed on the line after the
         label. \\
       & reference & {\tt reference = np(1963)} & If a reference
         is given it is printed on the output after label. No
         directive is allowed on the line after reference.\\
       & operators & {\tt operators xy 1 1 lz} & Listed in order
         of particles. The character `1' is necessary to denote the
         unit matrix. The literal `l' denotes lab angle
         dependence. \\
       &           & {\tt operators (xy,1)lz} & Listed in order
         2(1,3)4. The character `1' is not necessary to denote the
         unit matrix. \\
       & constant multiplier factor & {\tt factor = 2.0} &
         Multiplies operator. \\
       & squared multiplier & {\tt squared = 3.0} & Square root of
         the number multiplies the operator. \\
       & type\newline denominator & {\tt type = 2} & {\tt type =
       0} for cross sections \newline {\tt type = 1} for
       obs = $\frac{\tr AO_iA^\dag O_f}{\tr AA^\dag}$
       \newline {\tt type = 2} for obs = $\frac{\tr AO_i A^\dag
       O_f}{\tr AO_iA^\dag}$ \newline For cross sections default
       {\tt type = 0} \newline For other obs default {\tt type =
       1}. \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And here is the attempted compilation:

```
$ latex test-longtabu.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./test-longtabu.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/revsymb.sty))

Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/aps.rtx)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/10pt.rtx)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
\@input{defs.aux}
(./defs.tex) (./test-longtabu.aux)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Data is energy-averaged

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 as-sum-ing Gaus-sian en-ergy

Underfull \hbox (badness 1019) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Listed in or-der of par-ti-cles.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1715) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 lit-eral `l' de-notes lab an-gle

Underfull \hbox (badness 1715) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Square root of the num-ber

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmtt/m/n/9 type = 1 \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 for obs =

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmtt/m/n/9 type = 2 \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 for obs =

Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed
(longtable)                in table I on input line 72.

! Undefined control sequence.
\tabu@cleanup ...bu@naturalX =\tabu@naturalX@save 
                                                  \let \tabu@naturalXmax \ta...
l.72 \end{longtabu}
```

Here is the `.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=latex 2012.1.12)  28 MAR 2012 12:01
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test-longtabu.tex
(./test-longtabu.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
 Copyright (c) 2001 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <ogawa@teleport.com>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david@dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 596.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count79
\@tbpen=\count80
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box26
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1610.
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
\c@linecount=\count81
\output=\toks14
\@protection@box=\box27
\@topmark@saved=\toks15
\footins@saved=\box28
\pagesofar=\box29
\footbox=\box30
\pagegrid@col=\count82
Class revtex4 Info: Incorporating package {textcase}  [1998/11/12 v0.06 Text on
ly upper/lower case changing (DPC)]. on input line 3682.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@affil=\count83
\absbox=\box31
\c@part=\count84
\c@section=\count85
\c@subsection=\count86
\c@subsubsection=\count87
\c@paragraph=\count88
\c@subparagraph=\count89
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\c@figure=\count90
\c@table=\count91

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2009/07/16 8.31 (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip43
\bibsep=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count92
)
\widetext@top=\box32
\widetext@bot=\box33

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/revsymb.sty
Package: revsymb 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documenta
tion)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 118.
))

Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/aps.rtx
File: aps.rtx 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentatio
n)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/revtex4/10pt.rtx
File: 10pt.rtx 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentati
on)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip45
\LTright=\skip46
\LTpre=\skip47
\LTpost=\skip48
\LTchunksize=\count93
\LTcapwidth=\dimen102
\LT@head=\box34
\LT@firsthead=\box35
\LT@foot=\box36
\LT@lastfoot=\box37
\LT@cols=\count94
\LT@rows=\count95
\c@LT@tables=\count96
\c@LT@chunks=\count97
\LT@p@ftn=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty
Package: tabu 2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen103
\extrarowheight=\dimen104
\NC@list=\toks17
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box38
\sift@deathcycles=\count98
\@vwid@loff=\dimen105
\@vwid@roff=\dimen106
)
\c@taburow=\count99
\tabu@nbcols=\count100
\tabu@cnt=\count101
\tabu@Xcol=\count102
\tabu@alloc=\count103
\tabu@nested=\count104
\tabu@target=\dimen107
\tabu@spreadtarget=\dimen108
\tabu@naturalX=\dimen109
\tabucolX=\dimen110
\tabu@Xsum=\dimen111
\extrarowdepth=\dimen112
\abovetabulinesep=\dimen113
\belowtabulinesep=\dimen114
\tabustrutrule=\dimen115
\tabu@thebody=\toks18
\tabu@footnotes=\toks19
\tabu@box=\box39
\tabu@arstrutbox=\box40
\tabu@hleads=\box41
\tabu@vleads=\box42
\tabu@cellskip=\skip51
)
\@input{defs.aux}
\openout2 = `defs.aux'.

(./defs.tex
\wdo=\skip52
) (./test-longtabu.aux)
\openout1 = `test-longtabu.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: Patching array package. on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: Patching unrecognized longtable package. (Proceeding with f
ingers crossed) on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Data is energy-averaged
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 as-sum-ing Gaus-sian en-ergy
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1019) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Listed in or-der of par-ti-cles.
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1715) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 lit-eral `l' de-notes lab an-gle
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1715) in paragraph at lines 72--72
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 Square root of the num-ber
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmtt/m/n/9 type = 1 \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 for obs =
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 72--72
\OT1/cmtt/m/n/9 type = 2 \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 for obs =
 []


Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed
(longtable)                in table I on input line 72.

! Undefined control sequence.
\tabu@cleanup ...bu@naturalX =\tabu@naturalX@save 
                                                  \let \tabu@naturalXmax \ta...
l.72 \end{longtabu}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3216 strings out of 495062
 35700 string characters out of 1182644
 111360 words of memory out of 3000000
 6441 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 6283 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,13n,23p,208b,506s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

EDIT: I don't think it's relevant but here is the content of the `defs.tex` file:

```
\newcommand{\tr}{\mbox{Tr }}
```

Comment: There seem to be a incompatibility between `tabu` and `revtex4`. Using the article class makes it compile ok, however the table doesn't get split across pages. Removing the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` calls around your `tabu` fixes that.

Comment: Thanks, ArTourter. And removing `\begin{table}...\end{table}` takes care of the problem I had with `tabularx` that drove me to install `tabu`. I might, however, need `tabu` in the future -- any ideas on how to make it compatible with `revtex4` (other than not using `revtex4`!)?

Comment: Enclosing `longtabu` in a `table` environment makes little sense anyway: the contents of `table` *can't* be split across pages. The bug is annoying nonetheless.

Comment: Agreed, egreg. Had I thought about it...

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult to trace the source of the error, but I believe it has to do with the fact that `revtex4` redefines `tabular` and this breaks `lontabu`.

To begin with your problem, a `longtabu` or `longtable` environment should never go in a `table` environment, which is never split across pages.

Although `longtabu` doesn't work, you can get what you want by stating explicitly the column widths (load also the `calc` package):

```
\begin{longtable}{
  p{.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
  *{3}{p{.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
  }
```

but with `revtex4` you'll get a spurious

```
Package longtable Warning: Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.
```

message. This will disappear if you load instead the newer version of RevTeX:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
```

**Note.** The `revtex4-1` doesn't cure the `longtabu` problem.